# How can I create a postgres connection in my DAG to database on remote server?

Tags: python, airflow

I'm using airflow on my localhost. I want to create a Dag which can connect to the host which is not on my local PC.

There is no problem connecting to this database with:

```
AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
```

But I want to connect to
`jdbc:postgresql://10.10.10.10:5432/asd`  (host name is just an example)

What is the best practise ways to connecting remote databases?

```
create_report_2 = PostgresOperator(
        task_id='create_report_2',
        postgres_conn_id='inform_status_adb',
        sql="""
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS q_r_segment_status;
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS q_r_segment_status AS
            SELECT dbid, "content", "role", preferred_role, "mode", status, hostname
            FROM pg_catalog.gp_segment_configuration;
        """
    )
```

> ERROR - Failed to execute job 73 for task create_report_2 (connection to server at "10.10.10.10", port 5432 failed:
> FATAL: database "inform_status_adb" does not exist ; 6740

Comment: Are you encountering any errors? Please provide your code and include any errors

Comment: @MatteoZanoni
Yes, I have created a connection in Airflow UI.
After running Dag Ihave thi error:
ERROR - Failed to execute job 73 for task create_report_2 (connection to server at "10.10.10.10", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "inform_status_adb" does not exist
; 6740)

Comment: Well, the error seems to be quite self-explanatory! `database "inform_status_adb" does not exist`! Either you have missplelled the db name or you have provided invalid credentials

Comment: where can i specify the name of the database? In UI or in docker-compose.yaml?

Comment: If you already created a connection in Airflow UI, you can change it via UI as well. AFAIK, the database name is on the schema field.

Comment: @UmidUmaraliev Here is the documentation for creating a Postgres connection in Airflow: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/stable/connections/postgres.html